# SyntaxError: missing ; before statement in kendoui

Tags: popup, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

how come when i'm clicking on the update button popup kendo grid , this error ocurrs?

- The error in *Firefox* browser is in this form : `SyntaxError: missing ; before d.0=value`
- and in *Chrome* browser : `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number`

I've uploaded a video regarding this error for elaboration n stuff

[**Jsfiddle Code**](http://jsfiddle.net/psot98/mSRUe/25/embedded/result/)

[**Video**](http://youtu.be/H5DIGLCmCGE)

**Code**

```js
transport: {
    read: {
        url: 'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/sh/u9oxg5f6uweqh40/CbR3pNVg04/documentj',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'get',
        cache: false
        },
    update: function(e) { return true; }
}
save: function (e) {
    var that = this;
    $.ajax({
        url: '/echo/json',
        type: e.model.id == null ? 'POST' : 'PUT',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: JSON.stringify(e.model),
        success: function (data) {
            // Alertify.log.success(data);
            console.log('ok dadasaved');
            that.refresh();
        },
        error: function (data) {
            //  Alertify.log.error(data);
            console.log('no datasaved');
            that.cancelRow();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You need to at least call options.success in the transport.update definition. There is a working example in the documentation: http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#configuration-transport.update

Comment: In you JSFiddle click on "Tidy up" button and run it again

Comment: I clicked on a "Tidy Up"

Comment: I clicked on a "tidy up" but did not change and the same error occurs again.

Comment: chrome error:Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined and firefox:TypeError: r is undefined

Answer (score 2):

You should provide more code to detect what's wrong with your code, but read [this](http://www.kendoui.com/forums/kendo-ui-framework/data-source/unexpected-number-error-when-using-a-function-for-datasource-transport-update.aspx) may help you:

> Such error occurs when the transport definitions are inconsistent. In other words, if you would like to use custom transport method, all transport types should be defined as functions.
>
> Having a standard read transport and custom update is not supported. Please configure all transports as functions and let me know if the error still occurs.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error and for me the problem was that the `dataType` option was not set for all `transport` methods. I marked that line with a comment below:

```
var linksDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        read: {
            dataType: "json",
            url: 'read-url',
            type: "get"
        },
        destroy: {
            dataType: "json", /* <============ THIS LINE WAS MISSING */
            url: 'delete-url',
            type: "delete"
        },
        update: {
            dataType: "json",
            url: 'update-url',
            type: "post"
        },
        create: {
            dataType: "json",
            url: 'create-url',
            type: "post",
            complete: function () {
                $("#searchResult").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();
            }
        },
/* ... */
```

Comment: This was my issue. Thanks